# How to run subprocess with systemd-run and wait for it to finish

Tags: java, systemd, ubuntu-18.04

I need to run a child process from my Java process, which will kill the parent process. How do I make sure that:

- The child doesn't die when it kills the parent
- The parent waits for the child to kill it (the java call blocks)

I'm running the child process with systemd-run, which puts it under a different control-group, which means the child process doesn't die when it kills the parent. The problem with this approach is the parent doesn't wait for the child process to finish.

What I want is to block on the execution of the child process, letting it kill the parent gracefully.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question but if the child process should kill the parent, why can't you simply make the parent process exit after it has created the child process?

Comment: @RobertKock Not stupid at all. That what I use for a temporary workaround. The thing is, I want to know if after x minutes the child process is still running (meaning it didn't kill the parent), and hence there was a problem with the execution of the child process.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.
The systemd-run command has a flag called --wait, which provides the exact behaviour I was looking for.